# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application Service stuck on starting

Tags: 2013, web-services, central-administration

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application Service stuck on starting

[image]

I tried this command and got the error below

Command:

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

Error:

> Provision of service failed. Additional information: The path
>   specified cannot be used at this time.

IIS Reset neu didn't help either. Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Try to stop the service using the stop command `stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype spwebservice` and start again. It might take a long time if there are many web applications.

Comment: whiche service? there is no stop icon. I useed "stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype spwebservice" to stop the service but got the same error as above.

Comment: Try restarting SharePoint timer service and check again. If all else fails, try restarting the server and check again if you can.

Comment: Tried, didn't help.

Comment: These powershell commands didn't help either:
$svc = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.typename -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" -and $_.server.address -eq "servername"};
$svc.Provision();

Comment: Not sure how to solve this. When i got this issue, i stopped it using the stsadm stop command and started it again using the stsadm start command. It started working properly. You also might need to check ULS logs for the detailed error.